# Selenium C# integration With Neoload performance testing tool

Tags: c#, performance, selenium, devops, neoload

Could anyone help me to elaborate procedure for integrating selenium C# script with neoload tool.i wanted to integrate selenium C# and Appium C# coding with neoload .So I went though some steps in documentation and unable to run the example code and didn't get the point how we can integrated with selenium/appium C# script with neoload for chrome or any browser and perform load testing for web or mobile application with same tool .Could you please have a look on shared screen shot and help me to share valuable document with any simple example for understanding the concept/getting some confidence.Thanks for giving valuable time[image]

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code found here for the chrome driver: https://www.neotys.com/documents/doc/neoload/latest/en/html/#24364.htm

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
NLWebDriverFactory.AddProxyCapabilitiesIfNecessary(cap);
object proxyCapability = cap.GetCapability(CapabilityType.Proxy);
ChromeProfile profile = new ChromeProfile();
if (proxyCapability != null) {
    profile.SetProxyPreferences(proxyCapability as Proxy);
}

ChromeDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(profile);
```

Your problem is that you need to provide the ChromeDriver with a profile which has the `DesiredCapabilities` whereas you try to apply them directly to the driver.